# Network Sniffing Java Applet Authentication

Tags: java

Example, I have a java applet application, then this application is accepting userid and password as authentication. Can I sniff the userid and password on the network layer? Are the credential being sent on clear text format?

Last, how to perform MiTM (Man in The Middle) attack on java applet application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is it depends on how the Java Applet works. If it needs to connect back to a server to check the userid and password entered are correct, then I think it is in clear text. If it doesn't connect back to a server (since a Java Applet runs locally) then there's no opportunity for sniffing or man in the middle attack.

You can use [Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for packet sniffing.